# UIkit 3 Event is not working

Tags: getuikit

I've been trying to add a [tooltip](https://getuikit.com/docs/tooltip) to a button that only shown when certain conditions are met. I'm using uikit@3.0.0-beta.35. According to the documentation, I should return false on `beforeshow` event.

```
UIkit.tooltip($element, { pos: 'top' });

$element.on('beforeshow', function(){
  return false;
});

if(condition){
 UIkit.tooltip($element).show();
}
```

The problem is that the `beforeshow` function never fires for some reason. I even tried this syntax mentioned in [UIkit documentation](https://getuikit.com/docs/javascript#programmatic-use):

```
UIkit.util.on($element, 'beforeshow', function () {
  return false;
});
```

Unfortunately, none of these methods worked for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the docs has some mistake, switcher has the same problem. the event is triggered on `document` not the `target`. you can use  this syntax like this:

```
UIkit.util.on(document, 'event', '#target-id', callback)
```

the docs confused me a long time :(

Comment: Is `UIkit.util.on()` documented somewhere in particular?  I haven't come across it, only things like `UIkit.[component-name](".my_div").[method-name]();`.  Thanks.  *Edit:* I see it mentioned once here:  https://getuikit.com/docs/javascript

Comment: This is the one. I could not get my scripts to run on events after matching them up with the documentation, but the docs are WRONG. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is, that you're trying to listen to an event directly on the element, while the event is triggered on the document - there is an error in the documentation, as they say it's triggered on the element, but it's not.

There is also a fresh false [bug report](https://github.com/uikit/uikit/issues/3036) regarding this

```js
var $element = $('#hoverButton');
var $check = $('#tooltipToggle');

UIkit.tooltip($element);

$(document).on('beforeshow', $element, function() {
  if (!$check.prop('checked')) return false;
});
```

```html
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.35/css/uikit.min.css" />
<!-- UIkit JS & jQuery (not required by UIKit anymore) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.35/js/uikit.min.js"></script>

<div class="uk-position-center">
  <label>show tooltip <input id="tooltipToggle" class="uk-checkbox" type="checkbox"></label><br><br>
  <button id="hoverButton" class="uk-button uk-button-default" title="Hello World">Hover</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Switcher:

```
$(document).on('show', $('#switcherId'), function(){
    console.log('fired');
});
```

I may need this answer in the future too...